# Deseo convertir una Entry en entero para realizar una operación en Python con Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, entrada

El problema que tengo es en una aplicación en la que, por medio de un Entry, solicito un número que quiero convertirlo a tipo entero para realizar la operación `o = res * 2 - 1` y me sale el error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.

El código es el siguiente:

````
def abiri_ventana_hanoi():
    root.withdraw()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.geometry('380x300+700+100')
    win.configure(background='white')

    label_title = tk.Label(win, text="Hola, bienvenido a la Torre de Hanoi",
                           bg="blue", fg="white")
    label_title.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5, fill=tk.X)

    label_entrada1 = tk.Label(win, text="Ingrese el numero de fichas: ",
                              bg="white", fg="black")
    label_entrada1.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

    entrada1 = tk.Entry(win)
    entrada1.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

    num = entrada1.get()
    res = int(num)

    o = res * 2 - 1

    label_resultado = tk.Label(win, text="Las veces que toca mover los discos son " + o,
                               bg="white", fg="black")

    button_salir = tk.Button(win, text='Salir', command=win.destroy)
    button_salir.pack(side=tk.TOP)```
````

Comment: Estás obteniendo el contenido del entry durante la creación de la ventana. El mecanismo normal es hacerlo una vez el usuario presione un botón o una tecla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

revisé un poco tu código, una solución podría ser crear una función donde se realizará la operación, un botón que el usuario pulsará para calcular y un entry donde se muestre el resultado. Para mostrar el resultado en el entry que se creó para ese fin se utiliza en la función Calcular en este caso `entry_resultado.insert(0, o)`, y `entry_resultado.delete(0, 'end')` es para que cuando el usuario coloque otro valor diferente en la primera entrada, se elimine el resultado anterior y aparezca el nuevo resultado. **Te dejo el ejemplo del código adaptado:**

```
def abiri_ventana_hanoi():
    root.withdraw()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.geometry('380x300+700+100')
    win.configure(background='white')


def Calcular():
    num = entrada1.get()
    res = num

    o = int(res) * 2 - 1
    entry_resultado.delete(0, 'end')
    entry_resultado.insert(0, o)


label_title = tk.Label(win, text="Hola, bienvenido a la Torre de Hanoi", bg="blue", fg="white")
label_title.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5, fill=tk.X)

label_entrada1 = tk.Label(win, text="Ingrese el numero de fichas: ", bg="white", fg="black")
label_entrada1.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

entrada1 = tk.Entry(win)
entrada1.pack(padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
boton_resultado = Button(win, text='Calcular', command=Calcular)
boton_resultado.pack()

label_resultado = tk.Label(win, text="Las veces que toca mover los discos son:", bg="white", fg="black")
label_resultado.pack()
entry_resultado = Entry(win)
entry_resultado.pack()

button_salir = tk.Button(win, text='Salir', command=win.destroy)
button_salir.pack(side=tk.TOP)
```

Igual puedes adaptarlo a tu gusto, claramente. Espero haberme explicado bien y espero haber podido ayudarte en algo.